# How can I change music cover photo using APIC frame in ID3 tag?

Tags: python, id3, id3-tag

I want to change my music's cover image. I've tried:

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC

audio = EasyID3('11.mp3')
audio['artist'] = "Artist"
audio['title'] = "11"
audio.save()

audio = ID3('11.mp3')
with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as albumart:
    audio['APIC'] = APIC(
        encoding=3,
        mime='image/jpeg',
        type=3, desc=u'Cover',
        data=albumart.read()
    )            
audio.save()
```

[image: MP3 file with default icon]

But the cover has not changed. My project folder:

```
project
--- main.py
--- 11.mp3
--- img.jpg
```

Comment: If you open this file `11.mp3` in a specialized tool like Mp3tag, do you see the cover there?

Comment: Then your code seems to work fine. You would have to check in your File Explorer (Windows?) why the thumbnail was/will not be created. As long as you see the cover art in Mp3tag, you can be sure, that the cover is embedded in 11.mp3

Comment: But I use linux and I opened it with telegram and it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restart your file explorer